# Reporting Services: Position of Textbox or Tablix depending on parameter or dataset field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

In SSRS 2016, I have one report for multiple customers. Each customer have individual letterheads which are stitched behind the report after creation.

Now I want to change the position a textbox or tablix during runtime based on a x/y position value, which is stored in the application config for each customer.

How to achieve this? Entering an expression in the location property field doesn't work.

Without dynamic positioning I need to create a report for each customer which is a very bad workaround when you have dozens of them.

Answer (score 2):

To position things vertically, dynamically, or at least give the impression it's doing this then you could try the following.

---

**Be aware this is off the top of my head and untested.**

---

Let's say the smallest logo on the letter head is 3cm and the largest is 6cm.

Position a textbox (let's refer to this as `padTextBox`) starting at 3cm from the top of the report. Set the height to something small (0.2cm or something).

Next add your textbox or tablix immediately under `padTextBox`.

Now we need to dynamically set the height of `padTextBox`.

We can do this by adding a dynamic number of blank lines to it at runtime.

It sounds like you have enough info already to determine the Y position. You need to convert this to a number of blank lines which in turn will depend on the font size set in `padTextBox` so for example, Y position 5cm might need 3 blank rows in `padTextBox` so the the bottom of the text box sits at 5cm.

To add the blank lines, I think you'll have to add a bit of custom code as I don't think there is a built in function that can repeat strings.

The following should do it

```
Public Function GetBlankRows(n as integer) as String
dim s as string
s = ""
dim i as integer
for i = 1 to n
    s = s &  vbcrlf
next i

return s

End Function
```

Finally, we need to set the expression for `padTextBox` to something like

=Code.GetBlankRows(Fields!YLines.Value)

or

=Code.GetBlankRows(Parameters!YLines.Value)

you get the idea...

Hope this helps ...

Comment: Hmm, indeed it's a possible way to increase the Y position by adding empty lines. For the X position I can add spaces instead. But that is a very weak workaround because it works only with very simple one-line textboxes. As mentioned in the title I also have to tablix to position dynamically.

Comment: The idea is that you textboxes and tablix control are positioned next to the the "padding" textboxes, I was not suggesting you put the report content in them. You can add a few as required. As there is no native way to position control as you wanted this was was just a workaround. I know it's not perfect but I'm not sure what other options you have.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's not possible to set the position dynamically during runtime, what about setting it on build/deploy time?

The report files are XML. So having one master file for all customers under source control. When deployment is needed, a script (i.e. PowerShell) can open the file, reads the position for a specific customer from a config file or database and sets the relevant position values in the xml temporarily.
Then it builds and deploys the report for this customer and reverts the changes.